# Memory error for numpy operations: How do I bypass this?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working with a large array of positive numbers, say `num_arrays`. For example the shape of my numpy array is `num_arrays.shape = (10, 10, 3000, 100, 50)`. Now I have a function defined as

```
def func(x):
   return np.exp(-x**2)*np.sqrt(x)
```

When I call

```
func(num_arrays)
```

it returns me `MemoryError`. I understand that this is because my array size is too large, but is there any ideas as to how I can avoid this error and still achieve my results?

Comment: Try `numexpr` module?

Comment: Alternatively, you can check out `np.memmap`.

Comment: Break your array into smaller pieces and work on each individually?

Comment: How many copies of this array can your RAM hold?  You might save some space by making use of the `out` parameter of the functions - `exp`, `power`, `sqrt`, `multiply`.  My computer can't even hold one array of this size.

Comment: I have 16GB RAM, and the array I specified takes about ~6 GB, so I guess I can atleast hold one copy of the array. What do you mean by "You might save some space by making use of the out parameter of the functions - `exp`, `power`, `sqrt`, `multiply`"?